# Recyclerview from SQLite displays empty page on first time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am trying to populate `recyclerview` from an async task. and in Async task the data is fetched through API call and pushed to a SQLite table, then the list populates from the SQLite Table. The list fails to display on first load. But when I close the app and reopen the app, the list populates. Is this a general issue that need to be addressed properly or I am missing with something else?

```
public class KingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<King> kingList=new ArrayList<King>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("method_track","onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //To avoid the load on the main thread
        new DownloadDataAsync().execute(this);


    }

    public class DownloadDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Context> {

        @Override
        protected Context doInBackground(Context... ctx) {
            downloadData(ctx[0]);
            return ctx[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Context result) {

            Log.d("method_track","PostExecute");
            Cursor kingsRows=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(result.getApplicationContext()).getData(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS);
            kingsRows.moveToFirst();
            while(kingsRows.moveToNext()){
                String kingName=kingsRows.getString(kingsRows.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME));
                int battleCount=kingsRows.getInt(kingsRows.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT));
                int rating=kingsRows.getInt(kingsRows.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING));
                kingList.add(new King(kingName,rating,battleCount));

            }
            kingsRows.close();


            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(result);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mAdapter = new KingsAdapterRC(kingList,result);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void downloadData(final Context ctx){
            // Get a RequestQueue
            RequestQueue queue = HttpRequestHandler.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).
                    getRequestQueue();

            String url ="http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gotjson";
            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                            //Log.d("result_check",response.substring(0,500));

                            loadToDb(response,ctx);
                            populateList(ctx);
                            calculateRating(ctx);
                            logRatings(ctx);


                            //mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("result_check","Error");
                    //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            });

            // Add a request to RequestQueue.
            HttpRequestHandler.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
        protected void loadToDb(String jsonResponse,Context ctx){
            DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).truncate(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_DATA);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
                    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObj.keys();
                    HashMap<String,String> fieldVales=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        try {
                            Object value = jsonObj.get(key);
                            fieldVales.put(key,value.toString());

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // Something went wrong!
                            Log.e("loadTodb",e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_DATA,fieldVales);
                }

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                //Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
            }
        }
        protected void populateList(Context ctx){
            List<King> kingList=new ArrayList<King>();
            String[] kings;
            int kingsCount=0;
            String sql="SELECT DISTINCT "+DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_ATTACKER_KING+ " FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_DATA
                    +" WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_ATTACKER_KING +" <> ''";
            Cursor rows=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
            kingsCount+=rows.getCount();



            String sql2="SELECT DISTINCT "+DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_DEFENDER_KING + " FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_DATA
                    + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_DEFENDER_KING + " NOT IN ( "+sql+ " ) AND "
                    + DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_DEFENDER_KING +" <> ''";

            Cursor rows2=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql2, null);
            kingsCount+=rows2.getCount();

            kings=new String[kingsCount];
            int i=0;

            if (rows.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!rows.isAfterLast()) {
                    //your code to implement
                    kings[i]=rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_ATTACKER_KING));
                    i++;
                    rows.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            rows.close();

            if (rows2.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!rows2.isAfterLast()) {
                    //your code to implement
                    kings[i]=rows2.getString(rows2.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_DEFENDER_KING));
                    i++;
                    rows2.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            rows2.close();


            DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).truncate(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS);
            for(i=0;i<kingsCount;i++){
                HashMap<String,String> fieldValues=new HashMap<String, String>();
                fieldValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME,kings[i]);
                fieldValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING,"400");
                fieldValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT,"0");
                DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS,fieldValues);
            }
        }


        protected void calculateRating(Context ctx){
            Cursor battles_cur=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getData(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_DATA);

            if(battles_cur.moveToFirst()){
                while(!battles_cur.isAfterLast()){
                    String attackingKing=battles_cur.getString(battles_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_ATTACKER_KING));
                    String defendingKing=battles_cur.getString(battles_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_DEFENDER_KING));


                    if(!attackingKing.equals("") && !defendingKing.equals("")){

                        HashMap<String,String> whereConDfk=new HashMap<String,String>();
                        whereConDfk.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME,defendingKing);
                        Cursor cursor1=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getData(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS,whereConDfk);
                        double defKing_rating;
                        double defKing_battleCount;
                        if(cursor1.moveToFirst()){

                            defKing_rating=cursor1.getDouble(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING));
                            defKing_battleCount=cursor1.getDouble(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT));
                            cursor1.close();

                            HashMap<String,String> whereConAtk=new HashMap<String,String>();
                            whereConAtk.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME,attackingKing);
                            Cursor cursor2=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getData(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS,whereConAtk);
                            Double atkKing_rating;
                            Double atkKing_battleCount;
                            if(cursor2.moveToFirst()){

                                atkKing_rating=cursor2.getDouble(cursor2.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING));
                                atkKing_battleCount=cursor2.getDouble(cursor2.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT));
                                cursor2.close();
                                atkKing_battleCount++;
                                defKing_battleCount++;

                                Double defKing_rating_tr=Math.pow(10,(defKing_rating/400));
                                Double atkKing_rating_tr=Math.pow(10,(atkKing_rating/400));

                                Double defKing_rating_ex=defKing_rating_tr/(defKing_rating_tr+atkKing_rating_tr);
                                Double atkKing_rating_ex=atkKing_rating_tr/(defKing_rating_tr+atkKing_rating_tr);

                                String attackerStatus=battles_cur.getString(battles_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_ATTACKER_OUTCOME));

                                Double atkKing_rating_new=atkKing_rating;
                                Double defKing_rating_new=defKing_rating;
                                if(attackerStatus.equals("win")){
                                    atkKing_rating_new=atkKing_rating+(32*(1-atkKing_rating_ex));
                                    defKing_rating_new=defKing_rating+(32*(0-defKing_rating_ex));
                                }else if(attackerStatus.equals("loss")){
                                    atkKing_rating_new=atkKing_rating+(32*(0-atkKing_rating_ex));
                                    defKing_rating_new=defKing_rating+(32*(1-defKing_rating_ex));
                                }else if(attackerStatus.equals("draw")){
                                    atkKing_rating_new=atkKing_rating+(32*(0.5-atkKing_rating_ex));
                                    defKing_rating_new=defKing_rating+(32*(0.5-defKing_rating_ex));
                                }
                                String update_atkKing_ratingQuery="UPDATE "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS + " SET "
                                        + DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING+" = "+atkKing_rating_new+", "
                                        + DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT+" = "+atkKing_battleCount
                                        + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME +" =\""+attackingKing+"\"";

                                String update_defKing_ratingQuery="UPDATE "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS + " SET "
                                        + DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING+" = "+defKing_rating_new+", "
                                        + DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT+" = "+defKing_battleCount
                                        + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME +" =\""+defendingKing+"\"";

                                DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().execSQL(update_atkKing_ratingQuery);
                                DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().execSQL(update_defKing_ratingQuery);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    battles_cur.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        }
        protected void logRatings(Context ctx){
            Log.d("method_track","logratings");
            Cursor kings_cur=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext()).getData(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_WESTEROS_KINGS);
            try {
                while (kings_cur.moveToNext()) {

                    String name=kings_cur.getString(kings_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_NAME));
                    String rating=kings_cur.getString(kings_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_RATING));
                    String battleCount=kings_cur.getString(kings_cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_WESTEROS_KINGS_BATTLE_COUNT));
                    //Log.d("method_track", "logratings");
                    Log.d("rating_inspect",name+" - "+rating+" - "+battleCount);

                }
            }finally {
                kings_cur.close();
            }

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: debug your app..it will show you what exactly is happening for the first time....try removing  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: dont Intialize your recycler view inside onPostExecute do it  before calling asynch task and update the adapter's list by calling notifyDataSetChange  once you get the list from asynch task i,e inside onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
downloadData(ctx[0]);
```

Problem caused by `downloadData` method.

In `downloadData` method using `StringRequest`to get data from server. `StringRequest` process all requests on worker Thread  and return result back using `Response.Listener`.

`doInBackground` also done all work on worker Thread. so `doInBackground` method's Work Thread just executing `downloadData` method without waiting to get response from `StringRequest`.

No need to use extra Thread when using  `StringRequest`. just remove  `AsyncTask` and use only `StringRequest` to get it work properly.

Comment: When i use without async task i get this message `I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` and this is due to the method `calculateRating`

Comment: @DharanBro: Yes it's possible because you are doing other operations inside `onResponse` method also. so just use ` AsyncTask` inside `onResponse`  to do other operations

Comment: @DharanBro: arrage your code as StringRequest request -> onResponse -> run  `AsyncTask` to call `loadToDb(response,ctx);` method in `doInBackground` and call `populateList(ctx);calculateRating(ctx);logRatings(ctx);` from `onPostExecute`

Comment: thats the mess up I did with code. Now Its works perfectly. It made me to loose my night. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yo should not call volley `StringRequest` from `doInBackground` because `async task`  immediately shot the `post execute` method and your list will be empty so that it won't show any data. Simply use `string request` and after getting response save it in your 'database' and fetch from there(you can save and fetch the data from `database` directly or using async task).

For not just use `StringRequest` without any `async task` and test it.